# WPF UI Permissions, which are defined in database

Tags: c#, wpf, permissions, user-permissions

Till now I've used very simple User-Role version and controlled permissions per Visibility / IsEnabled / Command.CanExecute with converters:

```
 <TabItem Visibility="{Binding UserRole, Converter={StaticResource PackerVisible}}" >...
```

My converter looks like:

```
 <conv:UserVisibilityConverter x:Key="PackerVisible" Allow="Packer,Lagerleiter,Entwickler" />
```

It's relative easy if you have not much roles, but even so you have no good overview: who will get access to this or other UI elements.

One more bad thing is that UserRoles (stored in DB) used here as strings - `Allow="Role1, Role2, Role3"`.

And in my new project I have more roles/permissions, what makes this solution more ugly.

I've searched and found nothing how to implement it much better. A bit better is maybe to use enum for role names in code, but how to synchronise enum with database?

Other solutions i've found ([solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135953/assign-ui-permissions-wpf-dynamically), [solution2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/278199/Implement-UI-Element-Authorization-in-WPF)) are better, because they don't need converters, but permissions are set again as strings in XAML:

```
// AuthToVisibility
<Image ... Visibility="{op:AuthToVisibility "CanView"}" />

// AutoToEnabled
<MenuItem IsEnabled="{op:AuthToEnabled "CanClose"}">...</MenuItem>
```

What is the best way to handle permissions stored in the database towards UI? Is there any pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as nobody answers, I will try. I have a better (not ideal) solution.
First implementation, below I will write some words about it.

1. Permission Class:

   ```
   public class Permission
   {
       public bool IsAllowed { get; set; }
       internal List<string> AccessControllList { get; private set; }

       internal Permission(params string[] allowedRoles)
       {
           IsAllowed = false;
           AccessControllList = new List<string>();
           foreach (var role in allowedRoles)
           {
               AccessControllList.Add(role);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   - main property - `IsAllowed`
   - internal list of role names `AccessControlList` which are allowed to run/see some function/block
   - internal constructor to fill ACL.
     Small and simple.
2. PermissionController:

   ```
   public class PermissionController : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       #region Singleton
       ...
       //constructor
       private PermissionController()
       {
           Initialize();
           UserModel.Instance.LoginChanged += new LoginChangedEventHandler(UpdatePermissions);
       }
       #endregion

       //role names from database as string const
       private const string PACKER = "Packer";
       private const string CHIEF = "Lagerleiter";
       private const string QSWORKER = "QSMitarbeiter";
       private const string DEVELOPER = "Entwickler";

       PropertyInfo[] _localProperties;

       //Permissions defined as properties
       public Permission WEstart { get; private set; }
       public Permission WEreset { get; private set; }
       public Permission WEclose { get; private set; }

       public Permission Manage { get; private set; }
       public Permission TestPhase { get; private set; }

       private void Initialize()
       {
           _localProperties = typeof(PermissionController).GetProperties();

           WEwork          = new Permission(PACKER, CHIEF);
           WEreset         = new Permission(CHIEF);
           WEclose         = new Permission(PACKER, CHIEF);           
           Manage          = new Permission(CHIEF);
           TestPhase       = new Permission(DEVELOPER);
       }

       private void UpdatePermissions(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {            
           var currentUser = (UserModel)sender;

           //if user is logged out -> return
           if (!currentUser.IsLoggedIn)
               return;

           var permissionType = typeof(Permission);
           foreach (PropertyInfo property in _localProperties)
           {
               if (property.PropertyType != permissionType)
                   continue;

               var permission = (Permission)property.GetValue(this, null);
               permission.IsAllowed = false;
               if (permission.AccessControllList.Contains(currentUser.UserRole))
               {
                   permission.IsAllowed = true;
               }
               OnPropertyChanged(property.Name);
           }
       }

       #region INotifyPropertyChangedImplementation
       ...
       protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
       {
           ...
       }
       ...
       #endregion 
   }
   ```

   - Implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` (to use its properties directly in XAML)
   - uses Singleton-Pattern to have only one instance
   - has `const` strings for user roles defined in database. It's only one place in code where user roles are used as string values. If you need to update the role list - you should change only `const` list and initialization method (Permissions initialization).
   - subscribes to User.LoginChanged Event and updates `IsAllowed` properties of each Permission.
3. Different converters (`IValueConverter`) to convert Permission object (set in XAML) to Visibility/IsEnabled Property *(can post code if you need)*
4. XAML:

   ```
   <Image Visibility="{Binding Permissions.TestPhase, Converter={StaticResource PermissionToVisibility}}" ... />
   <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding Permissions.WEwork, Converter={StaticResource PermissionToBoolean}}" ... />
   <Button Command="..." CommandParameter="{Binding Permissions.Manage}" ... />
   ```

   - no need to edit XAML if you redefine role permissions
   - you can handle Visibility/IsEnabled/Command.CanExecute

Now I can manage User roles in GUI freely, role permissions are defined only in code. But it wasn't my requirement to manage role permissions.
Good enough is that if I need to update/change role permissions I will do it in only one place in code.

If you have questions or recomendations - I'm open for a dialog.

Comment: I am only just getting into this and have started a contract at a federal agency which uses a database-level data-visibility technology which employs a pattern I am unfamiliar with.  While trying to research it I came across your self-answered inquiry.  --  Surely I'm no expert on the use of roles, but what you have here looks logical, intelligent, and concise to me (for a solution you created by you / for you).

Comment: I really like your solution, can you share an implementation sample? I've some problems in the WPF binding part